# Eclipselink Does not execute any transactions on server redhat

Tags: java, eclipselink, redhat

I have a system (`jsf, mysql, tomcat 7, wamp server`) running in my local environment and it works when I run it on my server redhat on local network does not execute any transaction but does not show any error simply creates the connection

```
EntityManager in = emf.createEntityManager ();
```

And the object is not empty.

This is my code:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();   
try{
     Query query = em.createNamedQuery("EncaSec.findByEstado");
     query.setParameter("param",Obj.getEst());


     query.setParameter("codHab",Obj.getId().getCod());


     EncaSec result = (EncaSec) query.getSingleResult();
return result;
```

But the result value alwais have null value

It is worth mentioning that I have another application with `spring mvc`,  `hibernate` and the same data base the same tomcat, and it works correctly on server, so I ruled out firewall problems, or close ports

Comment: This code won't do anything without a transaction, so how have you hooked your persistence unit into JTA?  How are the JTA transactions configured, started and commited?

Comment: Thanks in advance the problem happens with any sql transaction, my persistence.xml said <persistence-unit name="persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

Comment: Finally I was able to solve it the problem was that it did not show for some reason ninungun error to make a backup of my local base and update the base in the server